How can I fix a printer stall issue on my Lexmark X9350?
I've had my Lexmark x9350 printer for some time now. About eight months ago, I encountered an error message saying there was a paper jam. The printer has stopped working, and I can't seem to resolve the issue. I've looked inside the printer carefully and can't find any jammed paper.
I'm wondering if I need to disassemble the printer to locate the issue, but I'm hesitant to do so for fear of damaging it. This printer is important to me, and I'd really like to get it working again.
Has anyone experienced this issue and found a solution?
Edit: I edited this using Google AI.

What is the error number? Have you checked the manual (e.g., https://www.manualslib.com/manual/92544/Lexmark-9300-Series.html?page=166#manual)?

Still "Paper jam", dispite no paper? Then there must be a jammed or broken sensor somewhere.

"What is the error number? Have you checked the manual (e.g., manualslib.com/manual/92544/…)?"It doesn't really give me an error but it only tells me that it had a starl and when I try to cancel it, it keeps mentioning a stall. It happened when I start it up and I cannot figure what is going on.

"Still "Paper jam", dispite no paper? Then there must be a jammed or broken sensor somewhere." Where do I find the sensor? It could be the problem as I could find any paper or debris anywhere.

There are various sensors in the paper path that track the movement of the paper. Any one of them may be broken, or a tiny piece of paper may interfere with one of them. A service manual would show them, but I cannot find one online.

I'm going to try that suggestion. I'll either need to search online myself or find someone who can help me. It's going to be expensive either way.
